# Conversion from an create-react-app (CRA) to CRA + Next.Js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I have a SPA made with `create-react-app` and it contains a forum where logged in users can post along with other features. The forum is simply a component within the app currently.

For SEO purposes I want to make the forum public and like **Stack Overflow** use dynamic routing for those posts and it should be viewable to anyone searching on Google without having to login. The user has greater abilities when logged in.

So I assume I have to implement **server-side rendering** on the forum using **Next.js**.

The problem is the rest of the code(**React + Redux implementation**) needs no changes and converting it to Next.js would be unnecessary. Is there a way to implement the forum within the CRA?

Comment: Maybe use [react-router url params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params), and add [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) for seo

Comment: @dhiravbro what approach you implemented , i have similar use case

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is! The official Next.js docs actually offers solutions on how to incrementally adopt Next.js.

There are two flavors:

- subpaths
- rewrites

Their documentation explains both in detail: https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/incremental-adoption